# Data cannot occupy more than 10240KB when serialized [android-workmanager]

Tags: android, android-workmanager

After I run the following code:

```
outputData = Data.Builder().putString("result", data).putInt("code", 100).build()
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data cannot occupy more than 10240KB
>   when serialized

So I read the code, I find something wrong in

Data class

[image: Data class]

MAX_DATA_BYTES could not over 10KB ???

[image: MAX_DATA_BYTES could not over 10KB ???]

Comment: It is not something wrong, it is stated in the documentation. If you need to save large records you should consider using ROOM and design your worker to get data from ROOM.

Comment: please foucus the point , My data is not over 10MB but only 15KB

Comment: Relax you are missing the point. DATA is limited to 10KB not 10MB and you have 15KB, 15KB > 10KB. You have exceeded the limit.

Answer (score -6):

Worker supports only primitive data types like String,boolean,double etc.

If you want to support objects too then convert Pojo object to json string object by making use of json eg:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStringFeedbackData = gson.toJson(yourcustomObject);
```

So you can save your to your data to  local DB then you can access the same in Worker class.